# RSpec: expect array of hashes in class_double recieve

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mocking

I want to test with RSpec a function my_test. The function calls another class's class method MyHelper.func in rails 4.
I used mock to illustrate func in class MyHelper, and I want to match the argument that func receives with some const values.

I used

```
expect(<double>).to receive(func).with(arguments)
```

But one of the const arguments is a hash with more than 2 items. When I test my 
function, RSpec throws an error:

```
received :func with unexpected arguments.
expected: [{"1"=>33.33},{"2"=>33.33},{"3"=>33.33}]
got: [{"2"=>33.33},{"1"=>33.33},{"3"=>33.33}]
```

Is there a way to match between the two arrays?
The code:

```
my_hash = [{"1"=>33.33},{"2"=>33.33},{"3"=>33.33}]
notifier = class_double("MyHelper").
              as_stubbed_const(:transfer_nested_constant => true)
 expect(notifier).to   receive(:func).with(my_hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky since you are comparing two things that are not equal when using `==`

```
let(:expected)  { [{"1"=>33.33},{"2"=>33.33},{"3"=>33.33}] }
let(:actual)    { [{"2"=>33.33},{"1"=>33.33},{"3"=>33.33}] }

expect(actual).to eq(expected) # fails
```

However, you can define a custom matcher and use it to compare the arguments:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :sorted_array_match do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected_hash = expected.inject({}) {|m,(k,v)| m.merge!(k=>v)}
    actual_hash   = actual.inject({}) {|m,(k,v)| m.merge!(k=>v)}
    actual_hash   == expected_hash
  end
end

it "should work" do
  expect(notifier).to receive(:func).with(sorted_array_match(expected))
  notifier.func(actual)
end
```

Note that this converts the array argument into a hash, so it assumes the arguments are arrays containing hashes with different keys. You might need to alter it to fit the actual data.

More info in the [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments).

Comment: Thanks! 
It's a great example of how to use our own matchers :)